# What happens to energy as oscillations die away

Tags: physics, classical-mechanics

I have the question "A punchbag of mass $0.60\text{ kg}$ is struck so that it oscillates with SHM (simple harmonic motion). The oscillation has a frequency of $2.6 \text{ Hz}$ and an amplitude of $0.45 \text{ m}$. Calculate:

**(a)** The maximum velocity of the bag.

**(b)** The maximum kinetic energy of the bag.

**(c)** What happens to this energy as the oscillations die away ?"

So I have answered questions (a) and (b).

For question (a) I worked out the maximum velocity to be $7.35 \text{ ms}^{-1}$.

For question (b) I worked out the maximum kinetic energy to be $16.21 \text{ J}$.

However, I am not sure how to answer question (c) and also are my other two answers correct ? If not could you explain where I went wrong.

Comment:  [hmmm](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2085592/calculating-amplitude-and-maximum-acceleration-of-a-moving-needle). (In all seriousness, this is a question for Physics.SE)

Comment: Energy is lost by friction, mainly in the attaching and against air, all converted into heat (with possible machanical intermediaries such as vibrations).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solutions to **(a)** and **(b)** are indeed correct.

For part **(c)**, kinetic energy is converted into heat energy (Enthalpy) due to the force of friction.